# How can I get field from second table via first table with foreign key from javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I have two simple models:
Book:

```
 public class Book
    {
        public int BookID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Author { get; set; }
        public string Year { get; set; }
        public string Publisher { get; set; }

        public int GenreId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("GenreId")]
        public Genre Genre { get; set; }
    }
```

and Genre

```
public class Genre
    {
        public Genre()
        {
            Books = new List<Book>();
        }
        public int GenreID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
```

With method from ApiController I get all data from table Books.
How can I get in javascript code Name of genre from table Genres using foreign key GenreId ?
I would like to write something like book.Genre.Name, but it does not work in js

Comment: Please show us how the `Action` that is sending the Book(s) back. Does it include details of the Genre ? Also include the `js` that performs the request. Update it in the question instead of comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code to serialize the object to return to frontend with json format:

```
var genre = new Genre();
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string data = js.Serialize(Genre);
```

Or in other way, you can use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for do that, this is a powerful json object convert lib.